# How do I reference functions in Rust?

Tags: rust

Trying to forward the function to a variable, in Javascript you might have

```
someFunc = someFuncAnotherTile
```

This way you can preserve the parameters.

In rust, how can I do this inside an implements for example

```
#[OpenApi]
impl TestRoutesApi {
    // Old annoying way
    // #[oai(path = "/test-hello", method = "get")]
    // pub async fn test_hello(&self) -> PlainText<String> {
    //     PlainText(format!("hello"))
    // }

    // Passing function, but it doesn't work.
    #[oai(path = "/test-hello", method = "get")]
    pub async fn test_hello -> test_hello;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, it might become available after [this RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2393)  or a successor is picked up again.

There is [`delegate`](https://crates.io/crates/delegate) which helps with the boilerplate when a struct simply passes the method call to one of it's fields.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be what OP is trying to do though, rather it looks like they want to assign an existing free function as a method, which I don't think is something that'll ever happen (one could imagine fully generalised UFCS, but it doesn't seem something with much draw in the community as far as I've seen).

Comment: Yes as I said "It's not possible".

Comment: You also said that it might become possible with the delegation crate / RFC, what I'm saying is that it does not look like that's what OP is asking for at all (to the extent that anything can be inferred from what they wrote).

Comment: Yes, I don't know how (if ever) delegation will be implement thus it might make what OP wants possible, I agree that it's not likely.